# Iterate through sub-data records and count up a counter-variable via SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a master and a detail table that look like this:

Master-Table:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Max |
| 2 | Kevin |
| 3 | Steve |

Detail-Table:

| ID | MasterID | Position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 2 | 0 |
| 5 | 2 | 0 |

The Position field has been added to the detail table and I would now like to count this up for each master data record.
I solved this with the Entity Framework, but it would be best if this could also be done directly with an SQL statement, as it is a large amount of data and would be faster that way.

So how can you count the sub-data records per master data record over and over again from 1, so that later the detail table would look like this:

| ID | MasterID | Position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 |

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Kind regards

Bati_84

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For updating Position column of DetailTable use below query.

```
With DetailCTE as (
select detail.ID as Id
    , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by detail.MasterID order by detail.ID) as PositionId
from MasterTable master
inner join DetailTable detail on detail.MasterID = master.ID) 
Update DetailTable
Set Position = DetailCTE.PositionId
From DetailTable dt inner join DetailCTE 
On dt.Id=DetailCTE.Id;
```

To know how it worked.

```
select detail.ID
    , detail.MasterID
    , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by detail.MasterID order by detail.ID) as Position
from MasterTable master
inner join DetailTable detail on detail.MasterID = master.ID
```

Comment: Ok, thank your very much....I try that a little bit later! :-)

Comment: But how can I save/assign the Position number for each record in the Details-Table?

Comment: @Bati_84 Are you saying that Position is column in your details table and how you will update that column in Details table?

Comment: Yes! It's a new column and I would like to update it, like in my post!

Comment: @Bati_84 I have updated my answer. I hope it works for you now.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it and give you an feedback, if it works! :-)

Comment: I have tried it today and it works perfectly! Thank you again! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use ROW_NUMBER for this pretty easily.

```
select dt.ID
    , dt.MasterID
    , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by MasterID order by ID)
from MasterTable mt
join DetailTable dt on dt.MasterID = mt.ID
```